# Как получить значение полей Pods в WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Я создал Pods для карточки товара, добавил туда 3 поля. Стал доставать через функцию pods() и fields(). Выводятся поля, которые я не создавал для Pods т.е. post_content, post_title. А я хочу получить только свои, можно конечно вычленить их, если какой-то префикс задать для этих полей. Неужели нельзя как-то проще это сделать?

Comment: В чем смысл вообще этим заниматься ради 3-х полей?

Comment: Потому что хрен знает сколько их всего может быть. А каждый раз допиливать с учетом нового поля тоже не вариант

Comment: Вы все поля в одном месте выводите или как?

Comment: Да, все в одном.

Comment: Может Вам репитер какой-то нужен?

Comment: Возможно по id группы получить список всех полей для страницы товара?

Comment: Никогда не работал с данным плагином на за минуту нашел документацию https://docs.pods.io/displaying-pods/displaying-custom-taxonomy-term-meta/